# Select2 load local json with multiple keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-select2

In the select2 "loading remote data" [example](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax)
the response json contains more information than the "loading array data" [example2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-array).

Is it possible to load a local json file containing array data as shown below
and make all keys selectable/searchable using select2, e.g. text, text2 and text3?

```
var data = [
  {
    id: 0,
    text: 'enhancement',
    text2: 'text2',
    text3: 'text3'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'bug',
    text2: 'text2',
    text3: 'text3'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: 'duplicate',
    text2: 'text2',
    text3: 'text3'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: 'invalid',
    text2: 'text2',
    text3: 'text3'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    text: 'wontfix',
    text2: 'text2',
    text3: 'text3'
  }
];

$(".js-example-data-array").select2({
  data: data
})

<select class="js-example-data-array"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Preamble:  I don't use this library.

Take a look at the documentation for 3.5.3.  It lists custom matchers you can write to match data based on attributes added to the select elements.  4.0 has wrappers you can add to those custom matchers to bring them up to date.

These custom matchers can look at any of the data in your object.

Since the options page in to docs are currently being re-written look at https://select2.github.io/options-old.html and search for the "matcher" option.  don't use the example here:  https://select2.github.io/examples.html#matcher
because it only hands you the term that was entered and the text of the option.

when you pass the options to your select2 initializer, do something like this:
(note that this is untested code).

```
 $(".js-example-data-array").select2({
      data: data,
    matcher: function (params, data) {
      // If there are no search terms, return all of the data
      if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
        return data;
      }

      // `params.term` should be the term that is used for searching
      // `data.text` is the text that is displayed for the data object

      // here include conditions for each of the attributes you want to match on
      // I've included text and text2 as an example
      if (data.text.indexOf(params.term) > -1 || data.text2.indexOf(params.term) > 1) {
        return data;
      }

      // Return `null` if the term should not be displayed
      return null;
    }
})
```

Good luck.